# FAT-only encryption

Tags: windows-7, security, encryption, ntfs

Are there encryption methods that **only encrypt the FAT** (ie only a few hundreds of MB instead of 600 GB in my case)?

The goal is to avoid to rewrite hundreds of GB of data for an encryption, and be able to revert easily to non-encryption in the case I don't want it anymore because of performance issues or other reasons.

If the FAT only is encrypted, of course the NSA could have access to the data with specific software that analyze the raw bytes on disk, but most thiefs could not access the data, because the file types / file names / beginning of files offset on disk will be missing (because encrypted).

Comment: Have you ever used PhotoRec or similar disk recovery tools? Whether the FAT got corrupted or was encrypted is irrelevant; files in popular formats can be recognized very easily using widely available software.

Comment: OK about easy photos recovery @grawity, but it might be a very easy way to stop non-geek thiefs to access my xlsx docx files etc.

Comment: @Bazj - while I think your approach is mildly novel I would point out that photorec can recover most doc formats - in fact it could be better for documents thrn pictures as they are small. One of Photorecs limitations is inability to handle large files which have been fragmented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want quick easy security for your data, lock it in a box. Or get a decent lock for the room. Or just move it to a real encrypted partition.

I almost don't want to answer, since photorec or maybe even testdisk will find the files anyway and this is a trivially basic idea, but you could backup the first meg or two of the partition, then overwrite it with zero or random data... mounting it then wouldn't be automatic. And windows may "helpfully" offer to format the partition. To read the data, write the backed-up data back onto the partition.

But anyone who can use google will try running photorec and find almost all the files anyway, not just an above-average thief but *anyone.*